# Checking memory consumption of css code on a browser

Tags: css, firefox

I have a css animation and transitions loop to rotate images without stopping, and once I start up the page, I notice that my laptop starts to consume more memory, and performance lags so I was wandering if there is a way to check in firefox how much memory that css animation/transition is taking so I could write lighter scripts and compare it as I go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has heap profiling which might be of use.

Note in Javascript, typically there isn't any garbage collection, all objects created will persist. That allows you to do things like reference internal variables in a web page which has been closed.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with the title. I don't have a javascript code. Only CSS. So, how about this "heap" profiling? where can I find it? is it a plugin?

Comment: Nope, it's included by default. Search for heap profiling in Chrome. You basically take snapshots at key times and save the results.